# How to prevent duplicate rows in sql cross join

Tags: sql, sqlite, filter

I have books, authors and links table. I want to get all books that has in their author at least one from chosen. Links is table with connections between them: if you want to set some book author you need to create row in links with foerign keys book_id, author_id.
What I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM books cross JOIN links
where user_id = 1 and
books.id = links.book_id and
links.author_id in (1, 2)
```

What i get

[image]

I want ot somehow get result without book duplicates, but I'm not sure that it is possible.
What can I do only with sql commands in this case?

Comment: Duplicates in SQL are based on *all* columns in a row.  I don't see any duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't require a cross join in the first place, and if you don't need those author_id and second id columns then you could use exists query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to avoid duplicate is to use `exists` with a correlated subquery rather than a `join`:

```
select b.* 
from books b
where exists (select 1 from links l where b.id = l.book_id and l.author_id in (1, 2))
```

This displays `books` that match, whithout their authors.

Another (probably less efficient) approach is aggregation and `group_concat()` to put all matching authors in the same row:

```
select b.id, b.title, b.year, b.price, group_concat(l.author_id) author_ids
from books b
inner join links l on l.book_id = b.id
where l.author_id in (1, 2)
group by b.id, b.title, b.year, b.price
```